# How to edit content of certain cell in a row into a table using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I using JavaScript to change content of certain cell in a table which created using JS using line below:
`document.getElementById("tableID").rows[x].cells[y].innerHTML = "someValue";`

But always get error says: (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cells' of undefined),
so what is wrong ?

```js
btnSave.onclick = function() {
  var table    = document.getElementById("table");
  var row      = table.insertRow(document.getElementById("table").rows.length);
  var cellID   = row.insertCell(0);
  var cellNAME = row.insertCell(1);
  var cellAGE  = row.insertCell(2);
  cellID.innerHTML   = " some id ";
  cellNAME.innerHTML = " some name ";
  cellAGE.innerHTML  = " some age ";
}

edit.onclick = function() {
  var x;
  for (x = 1; x <= document.getElementById("table").rows.length; x++) {      
    document.getElementById("table").rows[x].cells[0].innerHTML = x;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="btnSave">Save</button>
<button id="edit">edit</button>
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start at x = 0 in the for loop. Here's a working solution:

```js
btnSave.onclick = function() {
var table = document.getElementById("table");
var row = table.insertRow(document.getElementById("table").rows.length);
var cellID = row.insertCell(0);
var cellNAME = row.insertCell(1);
var cellAGE = row.insertCell(2);
cellID.innerHTML = " some id ";
cellNAME.innerHTML = " some name ";
cellAGE.innerHTML = " some age ";
}

edit.onclick = function() {
 var x;
    for (x = 0; x < document.getElementById("table").rows.length; x++) {     
        document.getElementById("table").rows[x].cells[0].innerHTML = x;
    }
}
```

```html
<button id="btnSave">Save</button>
<button id="edit">edit</button>
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```